# Map 1:1 and 1:N relationship without extra relationship key columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Assume I have the following DTOs:

```
class User
{
  string Name { get; }
  Permissions Permissions { get; }
}

class Permissions
{
  // User Parent { get; } - may or may not add this, whatever is easier
  bool SomePermissionProperty { get; }
  IEnumerable<NestedPermission> NestedPermissions { get; }
}

class NestedPermission
{
  // Permissions Parent { get; } - may or may not add this, whatever is easier
  bool SomeNestedProperty { get; }
}
```

so I have a User object. Each user has exactly one Permissions-object associated in a 1-to-1 relationship. And each Permissions object has several NestedPermissions objects associated with it it a 1-to-many relationship.

In theory, I believe it should be possible to have a table layout like this:

```
Table: User
  string Name

Table: Permissions
  string UserName  // refers to User.Name
  bool SomePermissionProperty

Table: NestedPermission
  string UserName  // refers to Permissions.UserName, which in turn refers to User.Name
  bool SomeNestedProperty
```

Is there any way to fluently map my DTOs in EntityFramework Core in a way that would generate such a simple table layout?

(so far I've only found ways adding shadow properties as relationship keys, but I am trying to avoid extra columns. Or, when I've added navigation properties to the child objects too, EF started overriding columns with relationship keys rather than their actual values, e.g. User.Name would contain some EF-generated value describing a key between User and Permissions, rather than its actual value)

Comment: This works out of the box, What problem did you encounter when mapping them? Only requirement is you'll need to add Username field to Permissions and an `Id` field to NestedPermissions class and tell entityframework that they are the Key fields by calling `HasKey()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx) and also normalize 1:1 relationships, as it is explained [here](https://geekyisawesome.blogspot.de/2011/03/database-normalization-1-2-3-nf.html).

The, as you call it "extra relationship key columns", are necessary for any normalization. Entity Framework generates the necessary columns and properties for 1:N and M:N relationships.

Answer (score 0):

EF uses some conventions for mapping PKs and FKs. If you want some custom names, you should configure it manually in you DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(c => c.Permissions).WithOne(i => i.User).HasForeignKey<Permissions>(b => b.UserName);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Permissions>().HasMany(c => c.NestedPermission).WithOne(c => c.Permissions).HasForeignKey(c => c.UserName);
        }
```

And your entities:

```
class User
{
  string Name { get; }
  Permissions Permissions { get; }
}

class Permissions
{
  public User user {get;set;}
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  bool SomePermissionProperty { get;set; }
  IEnumerable<NestedPermission> NestedPermissions { get;set; }
}

class NestedPermission
{
  public Permissions Permissions {get;set;}
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  bool SomeNestedProperty { get; }
}
```

This is a far FKs go. You still have to define PKs somehow, I assume this part you didn't show for brevity..